# Add dynamic html table to ASP form

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, html-table

I created a dynamic table with HtmlTable, HtmlTableRow and HtmlTableCell.
finally I've added it to the form with Form.Controls.Add(thisHtmlTable);

but the table was added in the wrong place...

```
`<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">`  

`<form id="formPort">`
```

`<!--this is the place where i want the table to be added-->`
   `</form>`
    `<!--the table was added here!!!-->`
`</asp:Content>`

does any one know how to add it inside the "formport" form?

Appreciate your answers,

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question correctly, but you can add `asp:Panel` inside the form and add your `HtmlTable` in it with `Controls.Add` method.

If you rephrase your question and provide more code[whole aspx structure]/detail than you will find accurate answer.

Comment: If it is the answer you are looking for then you should mark it as an answer !